# Tox: run tests only on certain platforms

Tags: python, testing, tox

I have test sections in `tox.ini` that should only run on Windows.

How can I configure tox to run a test section only on a specific platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tox 1.8+ has introduced new `platform` setting. Here's the quote from [the docs](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-v2.html#the-new-platform-setting).

> A testenv can define a new `platform` setting. If its value is not contained in 
>   the string obtained from calling `platform.platform()` the environment will be 
>   skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the info; it looks like that feature will not be available until Tox 2.0. The note at the [top of the page](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-v2.html) says "This is a draft document sketching a to-be-done implementation."

Comment: @ChristianLong why don't you try it? What I can tell for sure, multi-dimensional configuration, which is described on the page, is implemented in 1.8 and it works nicely. Docs may be just not up to date.

Comment: Tox 2.0 is out, and it adds a way to specify environments per-platform. https://testrun.org/tox/latest/changelog.html